# $H$ prime order implies $G/H$ cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups

I am revising some concepts of group theory, but I must admit that it's been a while and I have forgotten quite a bit.

I want to show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, where $|H| = p$ ($p$ prime), we have that the factor group $G/H$ cyclic.

In my situation, I have that $|G| = p^2$. In this case I understand that $|G/H| = |G|/|H| = p^2/p = p$. However, I don't understand how to prove that $G/H$ is cyclic.

I feel like the result might be trivial, as I am having trouble with finding a good explanation on the internet. Is there anyone who could explain this result to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not try to prove it yourself rather than look it up?

Comment: Am I being silly or is $G = C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$, $H = C_2 \times \{e\} \times \{e\}$ a counterexample (to the claim in your title, at least. As Hagen says, in your case all you need is the fact that $G/H$ has prime order)

Comment: I suspect that you are not “revising”, but rather “reviewing” some concepts of group theory....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Revise also has the meaning "reread work done previously to improve one's knowledge of a subject, typically to prepare for an examination" (Google's definition). Apparently it's a British thing, which I didn't know. It's quite common to talk about eg "the revision period before exams" here

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: Thanks! I was not aware of this. I figured it was a mistranslation. For example, in Spanish you say “revisar” for “review”, and so many people translate it as “revise” (much like the mistranslation of “limon” as “lemon” rather than “lime”, or “libreria” as “library” rather than “bookstore”...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every group of prime order is cyclic, in fact it is generated by any of its non-neutral elements (what else should that element generate if not the whole group?).

The claim in your title does however does not hold in general (i.e., when $|G|\ne p^2$).

Comment: Ofcourse! Thankyou, I was trying to proof the statement in the title, but now I see that that doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

To brush up your knowledge a bit : if for the normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ you would have $|H|=p$ is the *smallest* prime dividing $|G|$ *and* $G/H$ is cyclic, then $G$ would be abelian! Why? Since $G/C_G(H)$ embeds homomorphically into $Aut(H) \cong C_{p-1}$, it follows that $G=C_G(H)$, which is equivalent to $H \subseteq Z(G)$. Since $G/H$ is cyclic, it follows that $G/Z(G) \cong (G/H)/(Z(G)/H)$ is cyclic and this implies $G$ being abelian.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.  There are lots of examples where a normal subgroup of order $p$ doesn't yield a cyclic quotient.  Just to pick one out of the air, how about $D_8/Z(D_8)\cong V_4$.